# Maintaining the source ip during data redirection

Tags: sockets, redirect

I'm new in this site.

This is my problem: I have 3 different sources (IP: 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3) that send data (via UDP) to a single receiver (IP 192.168.1.4) on the listening port 8900 (same port for every source). I can redirect the traffic on 3 different listenging port on the receiver (one for every source i.e. 192.168.1.1 --> port 8910, 192.168.1.2 -->8920 and 192.168.1.3 --> 8930), 3 processes are listening on those ports.
If i loose a packet during the transmission, the process that should have been received this packet, try to send a retransmission request to the sender that is wrongly localhost instead of the original sender.
Is there a way to maintain the orinal IP during the redirection?

Sorry for my bad English and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

getsockopt(...,SO_ORIGINAL_DST) is what you are looking for.
(assuming that you did `iptables -j REDIRECT` or similar )

Comment: I create a script in c# to redirect the data on the ports. I create an udp listener on port 8900 and 3 socket to redirect the traffic to the 3 processes.  I couldn't use iptables (the 3 processes run on a cygwin shell that not allow iptables use).

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: In that case you lost org source IP in 'redirecting' script.